# how do i get rid of these warnigs about enums?

Tags: java, generics, enums, warnings

i would like to get rid of these warnings about unchecked conversion and parameterization without surpressing them.

```
interface Switch {
    void toggle();
}
enum A implements Switch {
    a1,a2;
    @Override public void toggle() {
        state=!state;
    }
    boolean state;
}
enum B implements Switch {
    b1,b2;
    @Override public void toggle() {
        state=!state;
    }
    boolean state;
}
public class Warnings {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Class<? extends Enum>[] enums=new Class[]{A.class,B.class};
        for(Class<? extends Enum> clazz:enums)
            try {
                Enum s=Enum.valueOf(clazz,args[0]);
                ((Switch)s).toggle();
            } catch(IllegalArgumentException eee) {}
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried `@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")`?

Comment: i should have added without supressing them. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't without writing your own `valueOf`.  `Enum` is defined as:

```
class Enum<E extends Enum<E>>
```

and `Enum.valueOf` is defined as:

```
public static <T extends Enum<T>> T valueOf(Class<T> enumType,
                                            String name)
```

Note the recursive type parameterization which implies that you can only call `valueOf` with a specific enum class (e.g. `A.class`), but not with a generic one, as a `Class<? extends Enum<?>>` is not a match because the two question marks aren't assumed to represent the same (unknown) type by the compiler.

So apart from using generic collections instead of arrays, you have to write your own `valueOf` method that accepts any enum class.

```
public class Warnings {
    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        List<Class<? extends Enum<?>>> enums = new ArrayList<Class<? extends Enum<?>>>();
        enums.add(A.class);
        enums.add(B.class);
        for (Class<? extends Enum<?>> clazz : enums) {
            try {
                Switch s = valueOf(clazz, args[0]);
                s.toggle();
            } catch (IllegalArgumentException eee) {
            }
        }
    }

    private static Switch valueOf(final Class<? extends Enum<?>> enumClass, final String name) {
        Enum<?>[] enumConstants = enumClass.getEnumConstants();
        for (Enum<?> constant : enumConstants) {
            if (constant.name().equals(name)) {
                return (Switch) constant;
            }
        }
        throw new IllegalArgumentException(name + " is not a constant of enum class " + enumClass.getName());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't mix arrays and generics. They do not work well together because generics in java is implemented using type erasure.

This should work.

```
interface Switch {
void toggle();
}

enum A implements Switch {

a1, a2;
@Override
public void toggle() {
    state = !state;
}

boolean state;
}
enum B implements Switch {

b1, b2;
@Override
public void toggle() {
    state = !state;
}

boolean state;
}

public class Test {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Class<? extends Switch>> enums = new ArrayList<Class<? extends Switch>>();
    enums.add(A.class);
    enums.add(B.class);

    for (Class<? extends Switch> clazz : enums)
        try {
            Switch s = clazz.getEnumConstants()[0];
            ((Switch) s).toggle();
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException eee) {
    }
} 
}
```

Comment: that breaks: Enum s=Enum.valueOf(clazz,args[0]);

Comment: In it's current state I don't see how it makes a difference whether you call A.a1.toggle() or A.a2.toggle().

Comment: i want to do: ((Switch)Enum.valueOf(clazz,args[0])).toggle();